# No rule to make target ... libm.a

Tags: g++, makefile

I get the following error when I try to compile my app:

```
*** No rule to make target `/mypath/lib/libm.a', needed by `/myPath/bin/appName'
```

Why is the linker looking for libm.a according to an absolute path?

Comment: You need to post your makefile to find out what's wrong with it.

Comment: He-he, I bet he doesn't *need*, but it would certainly be very nice of him :)

Comment: So, Nathan, any comments?  Code samples that don't work?  Anything?

Answer (score 6):

I start thinking of swithcing programming to psychic career...

> Why is the linker looking for libm.a according to an absolute path?

Because you told him to do so.  Most likely you've typed

```
# There were some rules that build your own .a libs
myLib.a: ...
   ...

# Handy rule to direct your libs into lib/ folder!
vpath %.a /mypath/lib

appName: appName.o libm.a
   g++ $^ -o $@
```

Whoops!  You need "system" `libm.a` (that's a math library, a part of glibc), but `make` thinks that you need your own static library.  It then adds the proper prefix and doesn't find any rule to remake `libm.a`.

A solution could be moving `libm.a` out of prerequisites.  That's the purpose of configure script or a special `make sanity` target to check the existence of system libraries.

```
EXT_LIBS=libm.a

appName: appName.o
   g++ $^ $(EXT_LIBS) -o $@
```

Comment: The error message is from make, not from the linker, so this answer is most likely correct.